# Basic hurdle in Python: preserving updated values from inside function

Tags: python, scope

I am sure this problem will be solved in 30seconds by someone who knows, but my attempts have certainly gone longer than that...

```
myString = 'pre-function'

def changeString():
    myString = 'post-function'

changeString()

print(myString)
```

Being that `print(myString)` is called after `changeString()`, why does `myString` still contain its pre-function value (i.e. `"pre-function"`)?

I would anticipate (and desire) `myString = "post-function"`, but cannot figure out the scope issues to get the function to properly return an updated value (and, yes, I have tried to insert `return myString` before the end of changeString() to no avail).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables within a function have function level scope, that is changes to the variable will not persist beyond running the function.

Using `global myString` as Kaeden suggested will solve this, but if you want your function to do more than change one specific variable that is hard coded, you're better off using `return`. For example, try this:

```py
myString = 'pre-function'

def changeString():
    return 'post-function'

myString = changeString()

print(myString)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had been looking for a solution along the lines of @Kaeden Wile, but that precise syntax is still not work as anticipated in my code.  I ended up finding my way to something like your version of the solution Clay Shwery—so I am marking that one as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly use the global variable `myString`:

```py
def changeString():
    global myString
    myString = "post-function"
```

Here's a good description of global variables in python: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp